# How to make a scalable IM client architecture for Android?

Tags: android, architecture, android-webview

## How to make a scalable IM client architecture for Android?

I have a stable im client developed with java in android.

-**but the native app have a limit in scalable**-

I want to：

1. Chatting Screen(The native app's Activity or Fragment) have many items(left or right) from each others, and the item have many different layout style.
2. App should dynamic update the different item layout sytle when user chatting, not update the ui from app update or release a new version.
3. App not too heavy.
4. App have a good performance at chatting.

So i remember the Hybird and H5 for my IM client.

### Hybird

It is good at lite project for many platform.

### Cordova

Same as above.

At the end some one give me a idea:

1. UI use the webview.
2. Controller and Model with native app interactive with webview.
   the mian task is that transfer the data between  controller, model with webview.

But I know that webview is too heavy too if just for drawing UI!!

So some one can give some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the beem or yaxim clients, both are open source, both are android, they should give you some ideas.

Comment: @arnt, thanks, yaxim is a native app solution, I need a Hybird solution which use H5 display content, native handle the data and interactive with h5 via JS interface.

Comment: I see: You're not looking for helpful source code, you basically want someone to do your entire homework for you.

Comment: @arnt sorry for that. Maybe my issue not clear. I have a stable IM app about native app. but now I got some new requirements , so I need a new Im app architecture which should be a hybird architecture . and I just need some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **1. React Native**

1. RN draw the UI
2. Native make a tcp connection with service at background
3. background notify the chat msg to RN for draw
4. hotfix to implements the dynamic UI style update

## **2. Weex**

1. weex draw the UI
2. Native make a tcp connection with service at background
3. background notify the chat msg to weex for draw
4. hotfix to implements the dynamic UI style update

## **3. WebView draw the UI**

1. webview draw the UI
2. Native make a tcp connection with service at background
3. background notify the chat msg to activity of webview for draw
4. hotfix to implements the dynamic UI style update(download the js and html)

**My solution**

> Webview + native tcp connection.